# PTIJ: Mr Potato Head on Shabbos

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Can Mr Potato Head carry stuff inside himself on Shabbos without a Kosher Eruv? And is there a difference if he's carrying food, body parts, or non essentials? Of course, his own limbs which can detach are considered part of himself (just as someone may wear a prosthetic limb on Shabbos without an Eruv, since it's considered "part" of the body).

Additionally, does Mr Potato Head need to check inside himself for loose change? So that he follows what Rebbe Chananya taught in [Shabbos 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.12a.4): "A person is required to check his clothing Erev Shabbos to ascertain whether he forgot an object in his pockets that he might come to carry on Shabbos."

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).